# Sorting PHP Results of a query on two fields

Tags: php, html, mysql, sorting, echo

I'm just starting to learn php. Everything I've researched references an array for sorting but I can't figure out how to make that work in this situation since one of my fields is constantly changing so I can't create a fixed array. Remember, I'm a noob so please explain in detail.

I would like to sort based on two fields how the results are displayed.

The first field on which to sort should be based on "SortOrder" as it correlates to the "TaskSubType" field (Displayed as Ticket Type on forms.  TaskSubType has the following values assigned and would work in an array:

```
MSP = 1
DEDICATED = 2
REMOTE SUPPORT = 3
EXPEDITED = 4
EXPEDITED - $25 = 4
STANDARD = 5
STANDARD - $25 = 5
```

So if the Ticket Type (TaskSubType) was selected as "Dedicated" then it would be sorted as "2" and if "Standard - $25" was selected as the Ticket Type (TaskSubType) then it would be sorted as "5".

The second field on which I want to sort is the Ticket Number (TicketNumber) field.  The value in this field is constantly changing since we have new tickets created every day so I don't know how to sort on this field with an array.

Main Goal:   I want to sort the results by Ticket Type according to the numeric value we have assigned to each type which is our repair priority and then sort within all the "Dedicated" or "Standard" to work each ticket in that group in the order it was created (each new ticket counts up by one).

The code below is what I have working up to this point and the weblink below shows how my results are currently displaying:

Webpage where results are shown:
https://fireytech.com/FireytechDatabase/hello.php

Code:

```
<?php

require '../../db_php/dbconnection.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM
            Tickets 
        Left JOIN
            Clients
        ON Tickets.CustomerNumber=Clients.CustomerNumber
        JOIN Contacts
        ON Contacts.ContactID=Clients.CustomerNumber
        JOIN Equipment
        ON Equipment.ContactID=Clients.CustomerNumber
        
        WHERE Equipment.PRINT = '-1' AND Contacts.DispatchContact = '-1' AND TicketStatus = 'Active' AND NOT TicketSubStatus = 'CUSTOMER PICKUP' AND NOT TaskSubType = 'ON-SITE'
";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo"<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Ticket Type</td><td>Ticket Number</td><td>Date Received</td><td>Last Edited</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Followup By</td><td>Sub Status</td><td>Repair Type</td><tr>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    $dr= date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['DateReceived']));
    $dl= date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['DateLastEdited']));
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['TaskSubType']}</td><td>{$row['TicketNumber']}</td><td>{$dr}</td><td>{$dl}</td><td>{$row['ContactLast']}</td><td>{$row['FollowupBy']}</td><td>{$row['TicketSubStatus']}</td><td>{$row['ItemType']}</td></tr>";
    
}
} else {
    echo "0 records";
}

echo"</table>";

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: In this case, you're best off accomplishing your desired sort simply by adding an `ORDER BY` clause to your SQL query.

Comment: It would be simpler to sort your SQL query using ORDER BY Ticket type, OrderNumber  after WHERE

Comment: And if you had explicitly referenced the attribute names in the select query we could have given you the exact code to paste the. BTW select "*" is usually bad practice anyway

Comment: the actual mysql field names to sort on are in the "Tickets" table and are called "SortOrder" and "TicketNumber"

Comment: You can do so with ```ORDER BY```. This clause comes at the end of your SQL query. Example : ```ORDER BY salary DESC, last_name ASC;```

Comment: Ok that was astonishingly simple.  I had tried that but maybe I didn't put it in the right place in my code.  Thanks Murosadatul!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Murosadatul gave me the clarity I needed.  I had tried the ORDER BY command but didn't realize I need to put it at the end of my SQL query.  Below in bold is where I placed it in my code so it worked if anyone else runs into the same problem:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM
            Tickets 
        Left JOIN
            Clients
        ON Tickets.CustomerNumber=Clients.CustomerNumber
        JOIN Contacts
        ON Contacts.ContactID=Clients.CustomerNumber
        JOIN Equipment
        ON Equipment.ContactID=Clients.CustomerNumber
        
        WHERE Equipment.PRINT = '-1' AND Contacts.DispatchContact = '-1' AND TicketStatus = 'Active' AND NOT TicketSubStatus = 'CUSTOMER PICKUP' AND NOT TaskSubType = 'ON-SITE'
```

**->->->->->->-> ORDER BY SortOrder, TicketNumber**
"
;
$result = $conn->query($sql);